# Making all possible symmetric 4x4 pixel images

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, iteration

I'm stuck...
I plan on making all possible 4x4 pixel images that are symmetric. That is that the left side of the image is the mirror of the right side. To do this I have made all possible 2x4 pixel images there is and stored them in a list of 2D array, so the first item will look like this, and then continue with 1 instead of 0:

```
[[0,0],
 [0,0],
 [0,0],
 [0,0]]
```

My plan is then to iterate through the list and create the 4x4 pixel image by reversing every array and combining it with the other one.

The final result how ever is where I get stuck! The result should be a .csv file where every row is one 4x4 pixel image like this:

```
row1,row2,row3,row4
0000,0011,1100,0000
1101,1010,0101,1011
```

What I have so far is this:

```
import numpy as np
seq = itertools.product("01", repeat=8)
data = []
for s in seq:
    arr = np.fromiter(s,np.int8).reshape(4,2)
    data = np.append(data, arr)
np.savetxt("test.csv", data, delimiter=",")
```

But that is just the beginning. I have been trying this for a while now and I'm staring myself blind I think! Does anyone have a neat way of managing this?

Comment: What does your output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In numpy you can rotate a 2d image as follows

```
image[::-1, ::-1]
```

to combine the two halves:

```
np.c_[image, image[::-1, ::-1]]
```

to get the format you want:

```
','.join(['{:04b}'.format(n[0]) for n in np.packbits(image, axis=-1) >> 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating through your images with this line, but not sure how 'pythonic' it is:

```
'{0}{1}{1}{0},{2}{3}{3}{2},{4}{5}{5}{4},{6}{7}{7}{6}'.format(*seq[i])
```

This takes your seq list and creates the right side for every tuple containing your left side image.